# "Credentials failed to obtain metadata" error when trying to auth Java client to Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I put together what I *thought* was the hello-world of **firestore** Java client auth, but it consistently dies with

*WARNING: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.
Credentials: ServiceAccountCredentials{clientId=104986335035620796437, clientEmail=junkbot@nextbot3.iam.gserviceaccount.com, privateKeyId=8e...11, transportFactoryClassName=com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Utils$DefaultHttpTransportFactory, tokenServerUri=https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token, scopes=[], serviceAccountUser=null}
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: 
**UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata***

"Credentials failed to obtain metadata" doesn't explain it - is my service account JSON wrong?  Why does it still give me that warning, and are they related?

```
val firestoreOptions = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
        .setProjectId("nextbot3")
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("serviceAccountKey.json")))
        .setDatabaseId("nextbot3")
        .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
        .build()
println("Credentials: " + firestoreOptions.credentials)
val db = firestoreOptions.service!!

val docRef = db.collection("users").document("a-user").collection("devices").document("a-bot")
println(docRef.set(mapOf("hello" to "world")).get())
```

my serviceAccountKey.json is straight from what I downloaded from the cloud (not firebase) project admin page:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "nextbot3",
  "private_key_id": "8edf2b2607309e5da929109550090a5818cd8511",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--...--END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "junkbot@nextbot3.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "104986335035620796437",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/junkbot%40nextbot3.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Comment: What's `firestoreOptions.service!!`?  I don't see that listed as a method on [FirestoreOptions](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/firestore/class-use/FirestoreOptions.html).

Comment: Kotlin shortcut, it means firestoreOptions.getService() and check that the result isn't null.

Comment: Click the link I provided in my comment to the documentation.  There's no getService method on FirestoreOptions that I can see.

Comment: I have a hunch that this is because you create `FirestoreOptions` via the default instance. That builder has an ADC provider that gets precedence over the `GoogleCredentials` you have specified. Try `FirestoreOptions.newBuilder()` instead.

Comment: @DougStevenson https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/ServiceOptions.html#getService--

Comment: @hiranya-jayathilaka I'll take a look thanks!

Comment: @hiranya-jayathilaka that plus a service account created from the wrong place (Google Cloud console instead of firebase page) was the issue, thank you so much!  If you'd like to create an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we create `FirestoreOptions` via the default instance (i.e. `FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()`), we get a Builder configured with Application Default Credentials. Those credentials get precedence over the service account you've specified. Use `FirestoreOptions.newBuilder()` to avoid this situation.

Comment: That is a really sneaky difference.  Odd that it didn't take stuff I explicitly specified as the priority.

Comment: This is insidious.  Was brought here from this thread, where it's clear that credentials conflict is root of the problem: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/2788