# Spring boot application with cloud run and cloud firestore

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, dockerfile, google-cloud-run, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have a simple spring boot microservice (gradle) that I want to deploy on cloud run and use cloud Firestore for storing some data. I configured it locally, so I can read and write data to firestore. If I create and run a docker image of the application locally, it works.
When I deploy it on cloud run, the application starts normally,

[image: Logs in cloud run]

except when it tries to read data from firestore (when I call an endpoint), I get the following exception in postman:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

On cloud, docker image is created with cloud build, through my github repo.

What should I do to make it work on cloud run?

Comment: Question. Is your local service account permissions are the same with those on the deployed env.?

Comment: Yes, I used the same service account

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772199/credentials-failed-to-obtain-metadata-error-when-trying-to-auth-java-client-to

Comment: Not really, I successfully connected to firestore from my local machine and from a docker container locally. The problem is only when the application runs on Cloud Run. There are some weird logs when I make a call to the service.

Comment: How do you deploy? How do you test locally with the same service account (how do you load it)? Can you share these pieces of code?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

I followed instructions from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers) and here it is used this library:

```
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:1.32.0'
```

Then I tried with this library (this is [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)) and everything worked!

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.1.0'
```