# Java Firebase authentication works on in IDE (Eclipse) but not when released

Tags: java, firebase, eclipse

I'm developing a small Java tool for internal documentation that uploads data to Google Firestore database, while another internal web app reads that data. So, being aware of the limited risks of this scenario, I decided to go and use a service account to login to Firebase for the upload part: I downloaded the JSON authentication file from the cloud console, and copied it into the execution path to be read by the Java code.
Everything works just fine when I'm developing on Eclipse: data is being sent with no error or issue, and I can read the data from the other web app. But, when I compile the tool and export it as runnable jar, the data upload fails: the seemingly relevant bits of the stacktrace are this:

> com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata
> [...]
> Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata
> [...]
> Caused by: com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthException: Error getting access token for service account: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure, iss: [my service account mail]

I read that this can be caused by system time, but in my case the time is fine on every computer I used to test this, and mainly this happens even on the same machine where I'm developing the tool: **in the IDE it works just fine, but outside, even using the same JDK (OpenJDK 16, by the way), it can't login to firebase**, and now I'm running out of ideas on why this is happening. I also checked the command line used by Eclipse to run the app, but, apart from a very long list of explicit dependencies, there seems to be nothing of use in there: the app starts just fine with no missing modules or libraries. Also, there is no other option set in the IDE's run configuration like env variables or command-line arguments that could be missing in another environment. I hope that someone can give me some ideas on how to shine light on this.

This is the code that performs the authentication, and runs with no error both in and out of the IDE:

```
  private static Firestore getFirestoreInstance() {
        if (firestoreDbInstance != null) {
           return firestoreDbInstance;
        }
        InputStream serviceAccountFile;
        try {
            serviceAccountFile = new FileInputStream(/*path to the credentials file*/);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            writeExceptionToLog(e);
            return null;
        }
        GoogleCredentials credentials;
        try {
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountFile);

            FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder().setCredentials(credentials)
                    .setProjectId(APIConstants.projectId).build();

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

            firestoreDbInstance = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

            return firestoreDbInstance;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            writeToLog("Error getting firestore instance");
            writeExceptionToLog(e);
        }
        return null;

    }
```

This is one of the methods that uploads data: the error seems to happen here since in the stacktrace there's a reference to `onFailure`, but I think the issue is not here, since the exception refers to the credentials:

```
    Firestore db = getFirestoreInstance();

    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection(APIConstants.pendingRequestsCollection).document(uuid.toString());
   
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    [...adding JSON data...]
    ApiFuture<WriteResult> result = docRef.set(data);

    ApiFutures.addCallback(result, new ApiFutureCallback<WriteResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            [...showing dialog with error...]
            writeExceptionToLog(throwable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(WriteResult writeResult) {
            writeToLog("Upload successful: " + uuid.toString());

        }
    }, Runnable::run);
```

The main question is: what could be the reason for this different behaviour? Same jdk, same data in the file, same packages...if I run it in Eclipse, everything is fine, but when I try to run the compiled JAR file, the upload fails with that error.

Relevant versions
Eclipse version 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Maven com.google.firebase, firebase-admin, 9.2.0

Comment: `new FileInputStream(/*path to the credentials file*/);` will not work if the file is in the JAR.

Comment: @howlger I thought of something like that too, that's why I put a try-catch for a `FileNotFoundException` when reading from the file, but, no, the file is in the classpath along with the compiled JAR (just to be sure, I just tested it by printing out the `credentials.toString()` value, and all the data is there)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: I used another class from the same dependency (following an hint found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772199/credentials-failed-to-obtain-metadata-error-when-trying-to-auth-java-client-to)), and used `FirestoreOptions` instead of `FirebaseOptions`:

```java
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountFile);
            FirestoreOptions bis = FirestoreOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                    .setProjectId(APIConstants.projectId).build();
            //no need to initialize an app now
            firestoreDbInstance = bis.getService();
```

To my surprise, the tool now works both in&out of Eclipse: the problem for me is now solved, but I still don't know why this could happen. I'll leave the question unanswered, in case someone comes up with an idea.